# How can I return all shards when using the Elasticsearch Python API?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to run a search against an ELK setup using the elasticsearch python API. It seems that by default, the search returns only 5 results from an index. How can i configure this so that it can return all the shards that are available from an index? The kibanna dashboard is showing 900 + shards, but the API is only returning 5. My code at the moment is:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

data = es.search(
    index='scapy'
)
```

Output from the script shows (top part):

```
{u'_shards': {u'failed': 0, u'skipped': 0, u'successful': 5, u'total': 5},
```

Screenshot from kibanna dashboard:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional parameter size can be set to display more results

```
count = es.count(index='scapy')['count']
data = es.search(index='scapy', size=count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must made a mistake in understand the result,
the result

```
{u'_shards': {u'failed': 0, u'skipped': 0, u'successful': 5, u'total': 5}
```

means that your data of index 'scapy' was located in 5 different shards and your search query got the result from these 5 different shards.
So the result must seems like this:

```
{
  "took": 1651,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2221327255,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "BL1E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPc",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "Cr1E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "Eb1E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "F71E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "KL1E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "LL1E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "NL1E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "R71E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "Sb1E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index",
        "_type": "logs",
        "_id": "TL1E-F8BH3R02gVcxkPd",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "deviceType": "4",
          "appVersion": "2.1.2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

There are 10 items in `hits`, that is because of the default size of result return was ten, so you can set the size in your query dsl,

```
GET /_search
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```